# getting error of plotly in jupyter : ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, jupyter

I am facing an error when I call the plotly library.

Here is my code

```
import plotly.express as px
fig = px.scatter(pivoted, x="variable", y="value", size="value", color="Industry",
hover_name="Industry", log_x=True, size_max=60)

 fig.show()
```

When I run this code,I am getting error like

```
javascript error adding output!
ReferenceError: Plotly is not defined
See your browser Javascript console for more details.
```

What should I do ?

Comment: What browser are you using? Also, have you tried restarting the browser and/or the kernel?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am using google chrome

Comment: IPython.utils.traitlets has moved to a top-level traitlets package.